# Connection refused to host using RMI

Tags: java

First of here is the Exception that I'm getting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V7ts.png

Just to give little background I'm trying to write simple RMI program that connects two  remote computers (Client/Server) using java's RMI.  I have my Server program up and running but when I run my Client program I get the exception showed above in the link.  Since I'm telling it to connect to 192.168.0.104 why is it saying "Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1"???

**Client**

```
public class Client 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
ServerInterface server;     
Registry registry;

try
    {
    registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("192.168.0.104", (new Integer(1099)).intValue());         

    server = (ServerInterface)Naming.lookup("//192.168.0.104/ServerTest");

    String serverString = server.getAndSetMessage("Connecting");

    System.out.println("Reply from the server is: " + serverString);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
    }


}
}
```

**Server**

```
public class Server extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ServerInterface 
{

static String hostName = "192.168.0.104";
String name;

public Server(String name) throws RemoteException
{
    super();
    this.name = name;

}

public String getAndSetMessage(String message) throws RemoteException
{
    return("My name is " + name + " Thanks for message " + message);
}

public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    try
    {
        String objectname = "ServerTest";

        Server theServer = new Server(objectname);
        Naming.rebind("//"+hostName+"/"+objectname,theServer);

        System.out.println("//"+hostName+"/"+objectname);
        System.out.println("I am Registered");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
        System.exit(1);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Does your hostname file contains 127.0.1.1?

Comment: I don't have access to /etc/hosts/ on these two machines, is there any other way to tell?

Comment: I dont know...  Could you try to set the system property java.rmi.server.hostname on the server?, like this: System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "192.168.0.104");

Comment: Woah, that worked.  I have been at this for two weeks and that line made it all work.  Thank!!!

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what exactly did that do to make it work?  Did it just set Server IP to 192.168.0.104 instead of localhost IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to add the following code to the server:

```
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "192.168.0.104");
```